# How to determine if connection was successful using QBFC to connect to Quickbooks

Tags: ms-access, quickbooks, qbfc

Here is the code I use to connect my MS Access app to QB Pro 2017 using QBFC:

```
Dim smgr As QBSessionManage

Set smgr = New QBSessionManager
smgr.OpenConnection "", "Job Management"
smgr.BeginSession "", omDontCare
```

This works great unless QB isn't open.  I need a way to test whether the connection was successful or not. I can't seem to find a code example on how to do this.

Thanks,
TD

Comment: Anyone ????????

Comment: if QB is not open (or if no company file open) it will throw an error.

Comment: I know that.  The problem is how do you trap for that error?  I am using MS Access vba to connect to QB but so far I haven't been able to trap the error thrown.   Anyone ever accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with QBFC is that it doesn't give you an option to check if it's open or if the company file is the same you are trying to open.

If you are okay with just forcing the current QB company file to close, then the following code should do the job.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim smgr As QBSessionManager
Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object
Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

Set smgr = New QBSessionManager
smgr.OpenConnection "", "Job Management"
smgr.BeginSession "", omDontCare

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Kill the current running Quickbooks process
    For Each oProc In cProc
        If oProc.Name = "QBW32.EXE" Then
           oProc.Terminate
        End If
    Next
    'Close the connection and try again
    smgr.CloseConnection
    smgr.OpenConnection "", "Job Management"
    smgr.BeginSession "", omDontCare
End If
```